# Installing core on 64 bit OS

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to install the Janestreet Core library on windows via cygwin and I get the following error message

> core unmet availability conditions, e.g. os != "win32"

Can I not use the application at all on my operating system?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and this is what the error message is saying, the Janestreet Core library is not portable to Windows, therefore you can't install it. I am not sure about cygwin and is it portable to it. You can also try to install more portable subsets of Core such as Core_kernel or Base.